# .Net Tracking Shipments

Tags: c#

I have a situtation where a user will enter in a tracking number  and i need to be able to figure out which company it was shipped from (UPS, FedEX, USPS, DHL) and then pass back a url that they can click on and send them to the right website.  Any suggestions?

Thanks Erik

Answer (score 0):

Use Google:

Make a call to Google like http://www.google.com/?q=[trackingNumber] and parse the response. You may even find a JSON/XML API for this.

Comment: That's a pretty expensive way of doing it, considering he just wants to display a link.